# Need to make Android app stop sounds from MediaPlayer when it detects a phone call

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

I have an Android app in which the user presses buttons and a sound plays based on the button pressed (uses MediaPlayer). Now when the user gets a phone call, the sound still plays. I want to be able to detect when the user is getting a call so that I can stop the sounds and to resume the sounds when the user is not talking on the phone anymore.

Comment: Have a look into this: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for registering broadcast receiver for [this action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED).